# How do i access value of JSON file using a string variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to fetch value from my Json file

```
let str = "awes123";
      console.log(`code value codeValueStorage  <<`, codevalues.str);
```

And this is the JSON file codevalues.json

```
{
    "awes123": "1",
    "qwe123": "2",
    "aws142": "3",
    "cxz132": "4"
}
```

how can I access the value 1 from JSON  from using  `codevalues.str` considering that `str = "awes123"`
please help guys I don't know what to do here.

Comment: what is `codevalues`

Comment: [`codevalues[str]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Thanks Latin, i was unaware with the syntax, it worked